# Symbol not Found : But checking for instance?

Tags: java, class

```
class Node {
   String guide;
   // guide points to max key in subtree rooted at node
}

class InternalNode extends Node {
   Node child0, child1, child2;
   // child0 and child1 are always non-null
   // child2 is null if node has only 2 children
}

class LeafNode extends Node {
   // guide points to the key

   int value;
}
```

So I have 3 different classes. Node. and Internal Node and LeafNode which extend Node. Internal Node has fields child0,child1,and child 2.

However, when I run this code, even though I check the instance of the object in the first if statement. I still get a "symbol not found error" When trying to access child0,child1, or child2 when p is of type node? What's wrong with my logic?

```
if ( p instanceof LeafNode || p instanceof Node) {
   System.out.println(p.guide);
} else {
   if (p.child2 == null) {
       printAll(p.child0);
       printAll(p.child1);
   } else {
       printAll(p.child0);
       printAll(p.child1);
       printAll(p.child2); 
   }
}
```

Comment: what is p. can you put whole code from where this if block is executing. also post error msg

Comment: *"even though I check the instance"* Something that is checked at **runtime**, vs. *"I still get a "symbol not found error""* A **compile-time** error. The first can have no impact on the second.

Comment: change below code like    class LeafNode extends InternalNode {
   // guide points to the key

   int value;
}

Comment: if its solve the problem. comment here. i will put it in answer with details

Comment: extend InternalNode  in leaf node class. It should work

Comment: `p instanceof LeafNode || p instanceof Node` can be rewritten to just `p instanceof Node`, since `LeafNode` *is* a `Node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that p is of type node and not InternalNode.

What you need to do is cast p to InternalNode before accessing variables that only exist in InternalNode.

```
if (p instanceof InternalNode) {
    InternalNode pInternal = (InternalNode) p;
    // access node0 and so on here.
}
```

### Your code should look like this:

```
if ( p instanceof LeafNode || p instanceof Node){
    System.out.println(p.guide);
} else if (p instanceof InternalNode) {
    InternalNode internalNode = (InternalNode) p;
     if (internalNode.child2 == null){
         printAll(internalNode.child0);
         printAll(internalNode.child1);
     } else {
         printAll(internalNode.child0);
         printAll(internalNode.child1);
         printAll(internalNode.child2);
     }
}
```